# find range between two specific times in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have an annual data set:

```
Jday = datenum('2009-01-01 00:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM'):1/24:...
    datenum('2009-12-31 23:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM');
DateV = datevec(Jday);
dat = 1+(10-1).*rand(length(Jday),10);
noise = 10*sin(2*pi*Jday/32)+20;
for i = 1:size(dat,2);
    dat2(:,i) = dat(:,i)+noise';
end
```

which represents temperature measurements recorded through a water column. I would like to calculate the temperature range between 06:00 and 18:00 for each day so that I end up with 365 values for each depth so a final matrix of 365x10.

I can specify the individual days by:

```
[~,~,b] = unique(DateV(:,2:3),'rows');
```

But I cant work out how to only consider values recorded between 06:00 am and 18:00 pm. Could anyone provide some information about the best possible way of doing this?

Amended: slightly long answer

```
Jday = datenum('2009-01-01 00:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM'):1/24:...
    datenum('2009-12-31 23:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM');
DateV = datevec(Jday);
dat = 1+(10-1).*rand(length(Jday),10);
noise = 10*sin(2*pi*Jday/32)+20;
for i = 1:size(dat,2);
    dat2(:,i) = dat(:,i)+noise';
end

for i = 1:size(dat2,2);
    data = [DateV(:,4),dat2(:,i)]; % obtain all hours from DateV array

    dd = find(data(:,1) == 6); % find 06:00
    dd(:,2) = find(data(:,1) == 18); % find 18:00

    for ii = 1:size(dd,1);
        result(ii,i) = range(data(dd(ii,1):dd(ii,2),2)); % calculate range
    end
end
```

Comment: I don't understand how you want to represent the _temperature range_ using only one value.

Comment: temperature range is between 06:00 and 18:00 for each day therefore there are 13 values

Comment: This is still unclear. You want to end up with a 365-by-10 matrix. I infer that 365 corresponds to the number of days and 10 is the number of measurements. Where does this 06:00-18:00 temperature comes into play? Do you want to average the values in this time period?

Comment: Correct for the matrix. If you look in the variable DateV it will have the time of day in hours 'DateV(:,4)' so for the first day i.e. 2009-01-01 I would like to calculate the range of temperatures between row 7 and row 18 i.e. 06:00 and 18:00 respectively. Therefore for the first day and the first measurement (depth) I could calculate this by: range(dat2(7:18,1)) I would then need to repeat this for the second column then third and so on, then repeat this procedure for the second day which will start in row 25. Is this any clearer?

Comment: I think so. I've posted an answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If [`range`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/range.html) is fed with a matrix, it operates on each column independently. We can use this to prepare a matrix where each column contains the values for the time interval of 06:00 to 18:00, and apply `range`.

1. The tricky part is manipulating your 365x24-by-10 matrix to get the columns right:

   ```
   A = permute(reshape(dat2', [10, 24, 365]), [2, 1, 3]);
   ```

   This should result in 3-D 24x10x365 matrix, from which rows 7 to 18 can be extracted.
2. The next step is to apply `range` and transform the result back into a 2-D 365x10 matrix:

   ```
   result = permute(range(A(7:18, :, :)), [3, 2, 1]);
   ```

Therefore, the full solution is:

```
A = permute(reshape(dat2', [10, 24, 365]), [2, 1, 3]);
result = permute(range(A(7:18, :, :)), [3, 2, 1]);
```

**EDIT**:
To make the solution even more generic, you can use `DateV` to obtain the indices of the desired rows:

```
idx = DateV(1:24, 4) >= 6 & DateV(1:24, 4) < 18;
```

and then use it in the solution like so:

```
A = permute(reshape(dat2', [10, 24, 365]), [2, 1, 3]);
result = permute(range(A(idx, :, :)), [3, 2, 1]);
```

Comment: Great solution. Although is it possible to make the code more generic i.e. instead of defining rows 7:18 the code use the datevector provided to find the row numbers of the time period specified. This will avoid error if the data does not start at midnight for a given day.

Comment: @user1155751 I'll see what I can do :-)

Comment: Great. I was thinking of doing something along the lines of -- newDateV = permute(reshape(DateV',[size(DateV,2),length(unique(DateV(:,4))),...
    length(unique(floor(Jday-datenum(DateV(1,1),0,0))))]),[2, 1, 3]); to find the hours of the day we want and then replace 7:18 with the indices of those hours in newDateV, although this seems like a long winded way.

Comment: I've amended my original post to provide a solution. The method I have shown works as required but it feels that I have over complicated the procedure.

Comment: @user1155751 I've revised the solution. Is this what you wanted? Note that it uses only the first 24 values of `DateV` and applies them on the entire dateset. If such time periods in different days contain different numbers of samples, the matrix cannot be reshaped like I suggest, and another solution would be required.

Answer (score 2):

Hourly date range between 01-Jan-1987 and 31-Dec-1987:

```
start_date = datenum(1987,01,01,00,00,00)
end_date = datenum(1987,12,31,23,00,00)
interval = datenum(1987,0,0,1,0,0)-datenum(1987,0,0,0,0,0) % 1 hour interval

date_range = [start_date:interval:end_date]
```

Very simple and works also for leap years.