# Get all the dates between two dates

Tags: matlab

I have these two limit days like

```
2004-01-01
2008-12-09
```

Now I want all the dates in  between them
like

```
2004-01-02
2004-01-03
........
2008-12-08
2008-12-09
```

How can I do it in matlab?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15093346/find-range-between-two-specific-times-in-matlab/17085594#17085594

Answer (score 2):

Used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17085594/1031417) answer for creating the array:

```
start_date = datenum(2004,1,1);                                   
end_date = datenum(2008,12,9);                                     
interval = datenum(2004,1,2)-start_date ;% 1 day interval
date_range = [start_date:interval:end_date] ;
```

For printing it in a readable (UTC) format (convert a serial date number back to a date):

```
datestr(date_range);
```

Here is some of the output data:

```
>> ans(1:365:end,:)

ans =

01-Jan-2004
31-Dec-2004
31-Dec-2005
31-Dec-2006
31-Dec-2007
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a combination of [**`datestr`**](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html) and [**`datenum`**](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) -

```
date1 = '2004-01-01'
date2 = '2008-12-09'
out = datestr(datenum(date1)+1:datenum(date2),'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

Output -

```
out =

2004-01-02
2004-01-03
2004-01-04
2004-01-05
..
2008-12-07
2008-12-08
2008-12-09
```

Comment: Why the call to `datevec`? I think `datestr` works fine with serial date numbers from `datenum`.